# Google Cloud Analyze Sentiment in JupyterLab with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis, jupyter-lab

I am using Google Cloud / JupyterLab /Python

I'm trying to run a sample sentiment analysis, following the guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries)

However, on running the example, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'SpeechClient' object has no attribute
>   'analyze_sentiment'

Below is the code I'm trying:

```
def sample_analyze_sentiment (gcs_content_uri):
     gcs_content_uri = 'gs://converted_audiofiles/Converted_Audio/200315_1633 1.txt'
     client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()
     type_ = enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT

     language = "en" document = {
     "gcs_content_uri":'gs://converted_audiofiles/Converted_Audio/200315_1633 1.txt', 
     "type": 'enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT', "language": 'en'
     }

     response = client.analyze_sentiment(document,
     encoding_type=encoding_type)
```

I had no problem generating the transcript using Speech to Text but no success getting a document sentiment analysis!?

Comment: Hi, did the answer provided by @aemon4 solve your issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem to perform analyze_sentiment following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) example. 
I have some issues about your code. To me it should be

```
from google.cloud import language_v1
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types

def sample_analyze_sentiment(path):
    #path = 'gs://converted_audiofiles/Converted_Audio/200315_1633 1.txt'
    # if path is sent through the function it does not need to be specified inside it
    # you can always set path = "default-path" when defining the function
    client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()
    document = types.Document(
        gcs_content_uri = path, 
        type = enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT,
        language = 'en',
    )

    response = client.analyze_sentiment(document)
    return response
```

Therefore, I have tried the previous code with a path of my own to a text file inside a bucket in Google Cloud Storage.

```
response = sample_analyze_sentiment("<my-path>")
sentiment = response.document_sentiment
print(sentiment.score)
print(sentiment.magnitude)
```

I've got a successful run with sentiment score -0.5 and magnitude 1.5. I performed the run in JupyterLab with python3 which I assume is the set up you have.

Comment: Thank you! I am enjoying this particular library and appreciate your response!